# What is causing an access denied on executable MobaSCPRinew.exe when using MobaXterm on Windows

Tags: windows, access-denied, mobaxterm

I've been a happy user of MobaXterm for years, this is a great terminal and X-window manager on Windows to access Linux machine and others. Recently, possibly since I upgraded to Windows 11 or changed laptop, I sometimes get the following error window:

```
An error occurred while starting the following MobaXterm subprocess: 
"%APPDATA%\MobaXterm\slash\bin\MobaSCPRinew.exe"
Access is denied
```

I could not figure out which action is triggering this error but it is pretty rare and seems to happen either when I switch from one tab to another or when I unlock my computer after a while but I can't reproduce it systematically. I'm using `MobaXterm Personal Edition v22.0 Build 4858`.

This executable exists on my system and the file properties mention that this is a "Command-line SCP/SFTP client". However, even after the error, the SSH Browser available in the side bar (provided you only show one tab) is still visible and working.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?
Thanks

[EDIT]
I contacted the support of MobaXterm:

- they told me it is a known bug related to the "Remote Monitoring" feature, which can display stats about memory, disk usage, connected users,...
- advised me to test the preview version 22.2 since the bug seems fixed in that release
  I used it for a few days and the issue never happened. I will download the latest official release 22.1 and, if it happens also in  that one, will wait for the official 22.2. I will close this issue once the bug is fixed in an official release.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, with some slight differences:

- Location seems to be the "Documents" folder of my "Onedrive":
  E:\OneDrive - xyz\Documents\MobaXterm\slash\bin\MobaSCPRinew.exe"
- I use the "professional edition" with the same license ID, so I suppose technically it is the same software.
- Issue only popped up till now after a reboot of my system, launching the MobaXterm and subsequently starting an ssh session.
- Restarting MobaXterm only (once) didn't produce the issue.

I now upgraded to 22.1. Since the release notes do not mention anything concerning this issue, I can't know for sure the problem will be solved. I'll report back when it reoccurs.

Johan

Comment: Thanks Johan. Since my original post, I contacted the support of MobaXterm:
- they told me it is a known bug related to the "Remote Monitoring" feature, which can display stats about memory, disk usage, connected users,...
- advised me to test the preview version 22.2 since the bug seems fixed in that release
I used it for a few days and the issue never happened. I will download the latest official release 22.1 and, if it happens also in  that one, will wait for the official 22.2.